# awk space between two words regex

Tags: regex, awk

My text file looks like

```
abc d="cde"
abc d="cde"
abc d="cde"
abc d="cde"
something abc d="cde"
something abc d="cde"
d="123"
d="123"
```

I have a loop with `awk`

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/d=/){sub(/d=".*"/,"d=\""++count"\"",$i)}}} 1;' inputFile
```

it gives

```
abc d="1"
abc d="2"
abc d="3"
abc d="4"
something abc d="5"
something abc d="6"
d="7"
d="8"
```

But I only want to have `abc d=` to be changed. so I updated the code to

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/abc d=/){sub(/abc d=".*"/,"abc d=\""++count"\"",$i)}}} 1;'
```

or

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/abc[[:space:]]d=/){sub(/abc[[:space:]]d=".*"/,"abc d=\""++count"\"",$i)}}} 1;'
```

None of above is working. The output I am expecting to be

```
abc d="1"
abc d="2"
abc d="3"
abc d="4"
something abc d="5"
something abc d="6"
d="123"
d="123"
```

so the question is how to include the `space` properly? `abc[[:space:]]d` or `abc d` or `abc[[:blank:]]d`? I tired all of them but not working.

Comment: If you test your 2 last tries, you will see that nothing is substituted, that's because no field matches that pattern.  One field is `abc`, another is `d=`, but no field `abc d=` exists. See answer below for how to use `sub` here.

Comment: if there is no double quote before `abc d=`, then just `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}$1~/abc d=$/{$2=++n}1' file`

Comment: @jxc in this question, `abc` and `d=` can exist in various field positions, e.g. 1 and 2, or 2 and 3, it is better not to split to fields at all.

Comment: with your sample data, when you use `"` as the FS to split the line, if there is not any other `"` before `abc d=`, the number will always sit in `$2` and `abc d=` is at the end of `$1`?

Comment: @jxc good idea, but `$1~/abc` also matches cases that should be excluded, e.g. `abc some text d="x"`. Plus what you mention, about possible `"` in previous positions. It is better to go with a `sub` alone, no fields splitting, as question asks to match `abc d=`.

Comment: it's `$1~/abc d=$/`, the line was broken in the comments. in case `"` exists before `abc d=`, you can use `="` as FS, just do some substr+index to find the number from `$2`

Comment: use `d="` as FS: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="d=\""}$1~/abc $/{$2=++n substr($2,index($2,"\""))}1' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Either split to fields and work on fields
- or do not split and test a replacement pattern for the whole line.

The problem in your question is not what pattern to use, both are good, but you use them on fields, while you should use them on the whole row.

**1st solution - sub(pattern, replacement)**

This is recommended according to your description ( `sub` applies to default `$0`).

```
awk '{sub(/abc d=.+$/,"abc d=\""++count"\"")}1' file
```

**2nd solution - split to fields**

```
awk '$(NF-1)~/abc$/ && $NF~/^d=/{$NF="d=\""++count"\""}1' file
```

Note that here more spaces between your fields are accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! seems not working in a loop `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/abc d=.+$/){sub(/abc d=.+$/,"abc d=\""++count"\"",$i)}}} 1;'`

Comment: My answer says that if you want to use `sub`, you should **not** loop. In general, there is absolutely no reason to loop for all fields for this task.